# Creating scalable solution without Futures?

Tags: scala, spring-mvc, concurrency, feign

Exploring the HTTP client binder Feign and I see that it [does not support](https://github.com/Netflix/feign/issues/24) callback results (DeferredResults). How then would I handle creating a scalable endpoint for performing many time intensive tasks in parallel? Trying to avoid something like this:

```
val slowComputation : Future[Array[Bytes] = ???

def endpoint = {
    Await.result(slowComputation(), Duration(1, SECONDS))
}
```

Comment: You can have a look to the scala parallel collections

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure I can because each tasks is independent, mutating an audio file for example per request. They aren't aggregated -- but processed and each returned to their respective client.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand this correctly: The 'def endpoint' is a synchronous blocking method, and you cannot change that fact, since it dictated by a framework?

Now, that means you have to block there waiting for the computation / IO to come back to you. That also means you use one thread up there.

I think the best you can do it to prevent 'overloading' that endpoint with to many waiting threads. So:

- Like you did, specify a timeout.
- Think about how many 'waiting threads' you're willing to accept. Then shed off more requests if to many are waiting. Like:

> ```
> val waiting = new AtomicInteger(0)
> val maxThreadsWaiting = 200  
>
> def endpoint() ={
>     try{
>        val numberThreadsWaiting = waiting.incrementAndGet()
>        if(numberThreadsWaiting > maxThreadsWaiting) {
>            // Return 'overload' failure. Like HTTP 503
>        } else{
>           Await.result(slowComputation(), Duration(1, SECONDS))
>        }     
>     } finally { 
>        waiting.decrementAndGet()
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks Gamlor, awesome notes, yeah exactly i'm limited by the framework so it's nice to hear that I'll have to manage the threads in some way and your example helps.